# Exposing Additional Form fields with RadioField in Flask WTForms

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

New to using WTForms, and I can't figure out how to do expose additional form fields as shown here: https://css-tricks.com/exposing-form-fields-radio-button-css/

Because radio fields have the choices parameter where a list of fields is provided, is there any way to customize each of those choices? Like have something different be exposed when different choices are selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is going to be a mix of python and javascript code.*

There are **2 common solutions**:

- Everything is already in the webpages and the unused fields are hidden until there is an action from the user (on the radio button).
- Make API calls to get dynamic custom choices.

You can create a route:

```
@app.route("/api/choices", methods=["GET"])
def my route:
    custom_choices = get_custom_choices()
    return jsonify(custom_choices)
```

Then in your javascript code, when the user clicks on a button, you make a request to the this route to get the custom choices.

Then when you check/validate the sent form, populate the choices of the field with the custom choices (in the example, get_custom_choice) as described in the WTForms documentation here:

> Note that the choices keyword is only evaluated once, so if you want
>   to make a dynamic drop-down list, you’ll want to assign the choices
>   list to the field after instantiation. Any submitted choices which are
>   not in the given choices list will cause validation on the field to
>   fail. If this option cannot be applied to your problem you may wish to
>   skip choice validation (see below).
>
> Select fields with dynamic choice values:
>
> ```
> class UserDetails(Form):
>     group_id = SelectField('Group', coerce=int)
>
> def edit_user(request, id):
>     user = User.query.get(id)
>     form = UserDetails(request.POST, obj=user)
>     form.group_id.choices = [(g.id, g.name) for g in Group.query.order_by('name')]
> ```
>
> Note we didn’t pass a choices to the SelectField constructor, but
>   rather created the list in the view function. Also, the coerce keyword
>   arg to SelectField says that we use int() to coerce form data. The
>   default coerce is str().

[Source](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields/)

The second solution requires more work, but it's lighter depending on how many different possibilities ou have for the choice. (And in my opinion: cleaner).